# Lorentz covariance vs invariance for $x_\mu p^\mu$

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, invariants

Is $x_\mu p^\mu$ Lorentz invariant and covariant?

I thought for a quantity to be Lorentz invariant, it should have the same value in every frame. However, unlike $p_\mu p^\mu = m^2$,  $x_\mu p^\mu$ does not seems to be a constant, so I am not sure if $x_\mu p^\mu$ has the same value in every frame. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 3):

This is in manifestly covariant form. And scalars have the simplest type of covariance: they are invariant.